# C++ :: operator definition

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and i understand that the :: operator is used to refer to namespaces. For example in the following object initialization, ifstream is a class in the std namespace but what does the second parameter in the constructor mean? - ifstream::in  -- to my knowledge ifstream is a class and not a namespace so please explain.

```
std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
```

Comment: You can declare other classes / typedefs / static members inside a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifstream::in
```

Is an alias for `ios_base::in` which is a static member in the class `ios_base` of type `ios_base::openmode`. This allows you to specify the mode of opening.

The scope operator doesn't only apply to namespaces but to classes / structs too since they have their own scope. thus, `somename::`, here `somename` can either be a namespace or a class / struct which on it's turn can have static members that you can access through the scope operator : `somename::foo`.

Comment: To be more accurate, it's not an alias for `ios_base::in`, but rather `ios_base` is a distant public ancestor of `ifstream`, which means that `ifstream` also exposes `ios_base`'s public attributes.  There's no aliasing in any semantic sense.